# Geodatabase disappears

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, sql-server, esri-geodatabase

I have an old ArcGIS 10.1 in my laptop. While I'm trying to create a geodatabase it gets created, but doesn't let me create new featureclass and/or feature dataset. I get the error:" failed to connect to database. bad login user."

Is there something I'm missing here?
I'm the admin on my laptop, and SQLExpress(V.2012), which has been installed by me. Though I don't know if I'm logging in as SQLEXPRESS' admin. I don't remember the credentials, I have definitely left it as default though.

---

This was long back, I think I gave up. Just then I installed and was working through instructions hence was not sure if everything got installed correctly.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure you've moved on since the question was asked but I wanted to pass along a doc on what might be happening here for users who land here.

[Error:  Failed to connect to database. Bad login user. Success when creating a geodatabase using ArcSDE workgroup license.](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/40881)

The gist of it is there was a bug at 10.1 (NIM083155) where the SDE Workgroup license string was not being entered into the registry key.  When this failure occurs, the database is dropped.